# How to add images as an attachment to php HTML mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

Is there any issue with my below codes?

I'm trying to add an image as an attachment to HTML mail send it from my form. Users have an option to add images and on click of submit button it will be uploaded and sent.

But an error occurs on click of submit and within seconds it automatically redirects to success page, but no email is sent from the form. If there any mistakes in my code could someone clean the code and point out the mistakes I have done?

Thanks

```
require_once "Mail.php";
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        // preparing attachments            
            $file = fopen($filename,"rb");
            $data = fread($file,filesize($filename));
            fclose($file);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"".$fname."\"\n" . 
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fname\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
$Subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Subject']));
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$filename = "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$EmailMe = 'shmshd12@gmail.com'; 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$filename="/uploads/file.jpeg";
$fname="file.jpeg";
$Messages = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'host',
        'port' => '##',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'mail@example.com',
        'password' => '*********',
    ));
$Body = "<html> html email</html>";
$Body1 = "<html> html email</html>";
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
$headers .= "From: Roberta <request@robertalollobrigida.ga> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: < reply@example.com > \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: user@example.com";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        // preparing attachments            
            $file = fopen($filename,"rb");
            $data = fread($file,filesize($filename));
            fclose($file);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"".$fname."\"\n" . 
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$fname\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$success =  mail($Email, $Subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from); 
            mail($EmailMe, $Subject,  $message, $ip, $headers, "-f " . $from); 

            if (success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/thanks\">";
}
else{
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/error\">";
}
```

Comment: Don't bother trying to do this yourself, it's really pointless, and your current code is unsafe. [Use PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), since you've tagged this question with it, and base your code on the example provided that does exactly this. It's shorter, simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its better to use [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

ot withot look to this example from php.net

> There differenece in body, headers of email (with attachment, without
>   attachment), see this complete example below: work great for me (LINUX
>   , WIN) and (Yahoo Mail, Hotmail, Gmail, ...)

```
<?php
$to      = $_POST['to']; 
$email   = $_POST['email']; 
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$comment = $_POST['message'];

$To          = strip_tags($to);
$TextMessage =strip_tags(nl2br($comment),"<br>");
$HTMLMessage =nl2br($comment);
$FromName    =strip_tags($name);
$FromEmail   =strip_tags($email);
$Subject     =strip_tags($subject);

$boundary1   =rand(0,9)."-"
.rand(10000000000,9999999999)."-"
.rand(10000000000,9999999999)."=:"
.rand(10000,99999);
$boundary2   =rand(0,9)."-".rand(10000000000,9999999999)."-"
.rand(10000000000,9999999999)."=:"
.rand(10000,99999);


for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['youfile']['name']); $i++){
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'][$i]) && 
   !empty($_FILES['fileatt']['size'][$i]) && 
   !empty($_FILES['fileatt']['name'][$i])){

$attach      ='yes';
$end         ='';

   $handle      =fopen($_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'][$i], 'rb'); 
   $f_contents  =fread($handle, $_FILES['fileatt']['size'][$i]); 
   $attachment[]=chunk_split(base64_encode($f_contents));
   fclose($handle); 

$ftype[]       =$_FILES['fileatt']['type'][$i];
$fname[]       =$_FILES['fileatt']['name'][$i];
}
}

/***************************************************************
Creating Email: Headers, BODY
1- HTML Email WIthout Attachment!! <<-------- H T M L ---------
***************************************************************/
#---->Headers Part
$Headers     =<<<AKAM
From: $FromName <$FromEmail>
Reply-To: $FromEmail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="$boundary1"
AKAM;

#---->BODY Part
$Body        =<<<AKAM
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="$boundary1"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--$boundary1
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$TextMessage
--$boundary1
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$HTMLMessage

--$boundary1--
AKAM;

/***************************************************************
2- HTML Email WIth Multiple Attachment <<----- Attachment ------
***************************************************************/

if($attach=='yes') {

$attachments='';
$Headers     =<<<AKAM
From: $FromName <$FromEmail>
Reply-To: $FromEmail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="$boundary1"
AKAM;

for($j=0;$j<count($ftype); $j++){
$attachments.=<<<ATTA
--$boundary1
Content-Type: $ftype[$j];
    name="$fname[$i]"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="$fname[$j]"

$attachment[$j]

ATTA;
}

$Body        =<<<AKAM
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--$boundary1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="$boundary2"

--$boundary2
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$TextMessage
--$boundary2
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="windows-1256"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$HTMLMessage

--$boundary2--

$attachments
--$boundary1--
AKAM;
}

/***************************************************************
Sending Email
***************************************************************/
$ok=mail($To, $Subject, $Body, $Headers);
echo $ok?"<h1> Mail Sent</h1>":"<h1> Mail not SEND</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: is those php with PHPmailer or without?

Comment: code above without phpmailer
for see how it work just visit its link there is clean example

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer


$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name